# Get all combinations of the first column's value and other column's value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an irregular table in Excel:

```
A A1 A2 A3
B B1
C C1 C2 C3 C4
...
```

How can I get the following its representation?

```
A A1
A A2
A A3
B B1
C C1
C C2
C C3
C C4
...
```

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722039/extract-categories-from-columns-into-duplicated-rows-with-new-category#comment24076827_16722039

Comment: A similar representation (not exactly the same) can be achieved by Paste Special --> Transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/683439/245595) to [Transform horizontal table layout to vertical table](https://superuser.com/q/683413/245595) using VBA appears to give exactly what you are looking for.

The code is self explanatory by virtue of working step by step.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's practically what I want. The only thing what I fixed is the value of the first column. Suggested script fills it by 1, 2, ... instead of A, B, ....

Comment: @Alex - That is what I had posted in [a comment below the linked answer](http://superuser.com/questions/683413/transform-horizontal-table-layout-to-vertical-table/683439#comment866443_683439). Now I have incorporated it in the answer itself, so it probably has the same code as your answer.

Comment: yeah, now your solution is the same as mine and it completely solves my problem.